# Vertex shader not changing vertex coordinates

Tags: attributes, opengl-es-2.0, shader

Ive been learning openGL ES 2.0 for the past few weeks and everything I have done so far has involved using one program. Im now looking to use multiple programmes so I can have different shaders doing different things.

The problem I am having is the new program and shaders are being used however they are using the vertex coordinates of the previous program. I have bound the coordinates to a separate index slot however there they are not being used.

I know the correct shader is being used because the triangle is flashing blue rather than red. Therefore I think its a problem with the attributes loading.

My code:

**Shaders**

```
char vertexShaderSource[] =
    "attribute vec4 Position;   \n"
    "uniform mat4 uMvp;          \n"
    "void main()                 \n"
    "{                           \n"
    "gl_Position = uMvp * Position; \n"
    "}                           \n";

    char fragmentShaderSource[] =
    "precision highp float;\n"
    "uniform float time;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "float c1 = sin(time);\n"
    "if (c1 >= 0.0)"
    "gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);\n"
    "else\n"
    "gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);\n"
    "}\n";

    char vertexShaderSource1[] =
    "attribute vec4 Position1;   \n"
    "uniform mat4 uMvp;          \n"
    "void main()                 \n"
    "{                           \n"
    "gl_Position = uMvp * Position1; \n"
    "}                           \n";

    char fragmentShaderSource1[] =
    "precision highp float;\n"
    "uniform float time;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "float c1 = sin(time);\n"
    "if (c1 >= 0.0)"
    "gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0);\n"
    "else\n"
    "gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);\n"
    "}\n";
```

**Bind attributes to separate indexes**

```
glBindAttribLocation(mShader, 0, "Position");
glBindAttribLocation(mShader1, 1, "Position1");
```

**Draw() function**

```
glUseProgram(mShader);
        checkGLError("glUseProgram");
        // ========================================================================
        // define vertex coordinates
        GLfloat Vertices[] = { -0.6f,  0.6f, 0.0f,
                               -0.5f, 0.48f, 0.0f,
                               -0.7f, 0.48f, 0.0f  };

        // ========================================================================
        // Clear the color buffer
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // ========================================================================
        // Set uniform function
        glUniformMatrix4fv(mMvpLoc, 1, false, MyMatrix);
        checkGLError("glUniform4fv");

        glUniform1f(mTimeLoc, (maGetMilliSecondCount() - mStartTime) * 0.001f);
        checkGLError("glUniform1f");

        // ========================================================================
        // Load the attribute data to the shaders
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, Vertices);
        checkGLError("glVertexAttribPointer");

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        checkGLError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");

        // ========================================================================
        // Draw verticies
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        checkGLError("glDrawArrays");





        glUseProgram(mShader1);
        checkGLError("glUseProgram");
        // ========================================================================
        // define vertex coordinates
        GLfloat Vertices1[] = { -0.5f, 0.12f, 0.0f,
                                -0.6f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.7f, 0.12f, 0.0f  };

        // ========================================================================
        // Clear the color buffer
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // ========================================================================
        // Set uniform function
        glUniformMatrix4fv(mMvpLoc, 1, false, MyMatrix);
        checkGLError("glUniform4fv");

        glUniform1f(mTimeLoc, (maGetMilliSecondCount() - mStartTime) * 0.001f);
        checkGLError("glUniform1f");

        // ========================================================================
        // Load the attribute data to the shaders
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, Vertices1);
        checkGLError("glVertexAttribPointer");

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        checkGLError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");

        // ========================================================================
        // Draw verticies
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        checkGLError("glDrawArrays");
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed the index of the attribute location for program1 to be in index slot 0. I also had to to take out the clear buffer on my second shader draw function so it didnt delete the first triangle drawn.